# MongoDB Equivalent for SQL query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

My sql query looks like this :

```
CASE WHEN ( DATALENGTH(school) > 0 ) THEN school ELSE 'na' END
```

I want equivalent mongo query for this :

I tried

```
             school:
               {
                  $cond: [{ $gte : ["school", 0]}, school, 'na']
               }
```

But it didn't work. Can anyone help me with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/) for this, in particular the **[`$ifNull`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/)** expression within the **[`$project`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** pipeline to return either the non-null `school` field value or the string "na" if the `school` field is null or does not exist:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$project": {                
            "school": { "$ifNull": [ "$school", "na" ] }
        }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 1):

The $cond expression should also work:

```
db.catalog.aggregate([{ 
    $project : { 
      school : { $cond : [ {$gt : ["$school", 0]}, "$school", "na" ]  } 
  } }])
```